# Form String while inserting in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do something like

> Insert into table(x,y) values("hi"+"5", 8)

Is there some way to do it in oracle?

Comment: One Google search later, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

Answer (score 5):

Use the correct concatenation operator, which is `||` in Oracle:

```
Insert into table(x,y) values('hi' || '5', 8);
```

You should also use single quotes for strings in Oracle (and in general, that *is* the ANSI standard).

Answer (score 1):

Use pipe operator to concat strings in Oracle

```
Insert into table(x,y) values('hi' || '5', 8)
```

Refer:- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

Comment: Perhaps the double quotes, the reason.. And I didnt downvote!!

Comment: I think concept is matter, OP has the same "", and thats not the OP original problem.

Comment: (didn't downvote) but if you post code that simply cannot run, it's not very helpful.